# sas/access interface to hadoop ,has anyone used it?

Tags: hadoop, sas

I cannot find any sid that contain SAS/Acess interface to hadoop.
so, how can I study it？
Anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> SAS/ACCESS Interface to Hadoop passes the following SAS functions to
>   Hadoop for  processing. Where the Hadoop function name differs from
>   the SAS function name, the  Hadoop name appears in parentheses. For
>   more information, see “Passing Functions to  the DBMS Using PROC SQL”
>   in Chapter 5 of SAS/ACCESS for Relational Databases:  Reference.

[Here is the full guide.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/achadoop/65227/PDF/default/achadoop.pdf)

To see wheter you have it or not use `PROC SETINIT;RUN;`

Comment: how to judge whether the sid  contains access interface to hadoop ？like “SAS/ACCESS Interface to Hadoop”？

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have used "PROC SETINIT;RUN" and saddly find no interface to hadoop.

Comment: that means is not installed on your machine